# npm script 'start' error in visual studio using iis

Tags: angular, visual-studio, npm, webpack

I have visual studio 2017 v 15.7.4

I have an SPA solution using asp.net core and angular

There seems to be an issue deploying to my local iis. In the run/debug options, if I select the "project" to be launched, things go well, but if I select IIS, I get this error when running:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:83:20
at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:224:22)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:262:24
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:178:20)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
if (npm.config.get('json')) {
```

Any help would be appreciated..I'm running VS as an administrator...
Thanks

Comment: Are you publishing SPA application first and then trying to host it via IIS?

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing the exact same issues. No I'm not publishing the website SPA first. trying to override the Development settings.

Comment: Were you be able to resolve this? How? Why Npm is trying to update the windows directory, it should use my profile. 'npm config get prefix' gives me my roaming folder

Comment: Any luck on resolving this?